# Split string on two subpatterns into data.frame

Tags: r, regex, string, strsplit

I have a character vector:

```
s <- "0 / 10 %(% 1 / 11 %-% 2 / 12 %)% 3 / 13"
```

The goal is to split it on both `/` and `%*%` into (x,y) points and z symbols:

```
data.frame(x = c(0,1,2,3), y = c(10,11,12,13), z = c("(", "-", ")", NA),
           stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
  x  y    z
1 0 10    (
2 1 11    -
3 2 12    )
4 3 13 <NA>
```

Notes:

- The `/` separates points: I want to split `x / y` into the `x`-part and `y`-part.
- The second split `%*%` should go into a column `z` of symbols, but without the `%`'s;

I tried various versions of `strsplit` with no success:

```
trimws(unlist(strsplit(s, "[/(%*%)]")))
[1] "0" "0" ""  ""  "1" "1" "-" "2" "2" ""  ""  "3" "3"
```

*Issues*:

- the `-` does not get caught by `(%*%)`, why?
- I have empty string parts in it, why?
- I have no idea how to store the `split`s into the `z` column

Comment: Note that `strsplit(s, '%[(-)]%')` throws away your split patterns, which would be ok for '/' but not for capturing the middle character between percents. If you're guaranteeing there's a space after the right-percent, you could just do `strsplit(s, '% ')`; else you'll need a regex with right-lookahead assertion for digits. It's easier and clearer to do two splits, do the first split on the '% ' right-percent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This solves your problem:

```r
str <- "0 / 10 %(% 1 / 11 %-% 2 / 12 %)% 3 / 13"

str_sub <- gsub("[%/]","",str) #sub all % and / with ""
str_split <- strsplit(str_sub,"\\s+")[[1]] #split by whitespace
str_corr <- c(str_split,rep(NA,3-length(str_split) %% 3)) #correct length, fill the end with NAs

df <- as.data.frame(matrix(str_corr,ncol=3,byrow=TRUE)) #convert to data.frame via matrix
colnames(df) <- c("x","y","z") #set colnames
```

<sup>Created on 2019-04-09 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.1)</sup>

To your first Issue:

1. `%*%`does not capture the `-` because you ask the regex to repeat `%` 0 or more times (with the *) but are not asking for a `-`.

Answer (score 1):

This is subtle because `strsplit(s, '%[(-)]%')` throws away your split patterns, which would be ok for '/' but not for capturing the middle character between percents. If you're guaranteeing there's a space after the right-percent, you could just do strsplit(s, '% '); else you'll need a regex with right-lookahead assertion for digits.

It's easier and clearer to do two splits: do the first split on the '% ' right-percent:

```
s2 <- strsplit(s, '% ')[[1]]

"0 / 10 %(" "1 / 11 %-" "2 / 12 %)" "3 / 13"
```

Now you do a second split on both the '/' and left-percent characters:

```
> strsplit(s2, '[%/]')

[[1]]
[1] "0 "   " 10 " "("   

[[2]]
[1] "1 "   " 11 " "-"   

[[3]]
[1] "2 "   " 12 " ")"   

[[4]]
[1] "3 "  " 13"
```

The slight problem with this it's ragged; the last line has no symbol.
Since in your case it seems safe to assume that only happens at the end of line, easiest kludge is to add a '%$% ' end-of-line char (note the trailing space), then map `$` -> NA later.